# Laravel auth doesn't work but all routes are properly created

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-5

I created routes and controllers for login and register, but when I try to go to either GET login or POST login, the pages don't show up, and no errors are logged in php_error.log (strange). I did make:auth and the routes and controllers get created, but I cannot get anything useful neither from GET /login or from POST /login requests. On GET on /login I get this error on the page

```
ErrorException in a19535dcda3ed1d86f3228aa05198ae78974da4f.php line 12:
Undefined variable: errors (View: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/gos-twilio/server-laravel/resources/views/auth/login.blade.php)
in a19535dcda3ed1d86f3228aa05198ae78974da4f.php line 12
at CompilerEngine->handleViewException(object(ErrorException), '1') in PhpEngine.php line 44
at PhpEngine->evaluatePath('/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/gos-twilio/server-laravel/storage/framework/views/a19535dcda3ed1d86f3228aa05198ae78974da4f.php', array('__env' => object(Factory), 'app' => object(Application))) in CompilerEngine.php line 59
```

and no errors in php_error.log. On POST /login I can get my own output, from my custom method in `AuthController` but I doubt anything applies to it, such as automatic connection to the User model, login throttling etc, since I created my own method for this request inside the `/http/controller/auth/AuthController.php` called `protected function login()` What am I doing wrong? This is the output of `php artisan route:list` :

```
+--------+----------+-------------------------+----------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------+------------+
| Domain | Method   | URI                     | Name           | Action                                                          | Middleware |
+--------+----------+-------------------------+----------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------+------------+
|        | GET|HEAD | /                       | home           | Closure                                                         |            |
|        | GET|HEAD | home                    |                | App\Http\Controllers\HomeController@index                       | auth       |
|        | GET|HEAD | login                   |                | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\AuthController@showLoginForm          | guest      |
|        | POST     | login                   |                | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\AuthController@login                  | guest      |
|        | GET|HEAD | logout                  |                | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\AuthController@logout                 |            |
|        | POST     | password/email          |                | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\PasswordController@sendResetLinkEmail | guest      |
|        | POST     | password/reset          |                | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\PasswordController@reset              | guest      |
|        | GET|HEAD | password/reset/{token?} |                | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\PasswordController@showResetForm      | guest      |
|        | GET|HEAD | register                |                | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\AuthController@showRegistrationForm   | guest      |
|        | POST     | register                |                | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\AuthController@register               | guest      |
|        | POST     | token                   | token-generate | App\Http\Controllers\TokenController@generate                   |            |
+--------+----------+-------------------------+----------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------+------------+
```

Routes are defined in app/http/routes.php which has this content:

```
<?php
Route::get(
    '/',
    ['as' => 'home', function () {
        return response()->view('index');
    }]
);
Route::post(
    '/token',
    ['uses' => 'TokenController@generate', 'as' => 'token-generate']
);
Route::auth();
Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index');
Route::auth();
Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index');
Route::auth();
Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index');
Route::auth();
Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index');
```

Comment: Hi! Yes, ok I will update the question with these details.

Comment: How can I get version of Laravel? I cannot find routes/web.php file....

Comment: When I do php artisan route:list, no, I don't get version. When I run php artisan, I get this version info:
Laravel Framework version 5.2.45

Comment: The routes are created when I did make:auth command.

Comment: Right, my fault, sorry, only `php artisan` shows the version. Ok, 5.2 ... really no clue, never worked with it. If you can, upgrade to at least ... 5.5 I think, things change a lot until that version, preferably 5.8 if you want to stay on L5. No help here, sorry. Good luck

Comment: any reason you don't have the `web` middleware group assigned to these routes? which is needed for sessions and also where the `ShareErrorsFromSession` middleware is assigned (which gives you the `$errors` variable in your views)

Comment: @lagbox yeah, I took it from a git repo online, and then went ahead trying to modify it. I don't know, but routes do work, for exmple the one for token works. The route I am talking about is POST /token

Comment: you need to apply the `web` middleware to these routes otherwise you won't have sessions 
(which means no authentication) and you won't have an `$errors` variable in your views ... so add this middleware

Comment: @lagbox ok, that makes sense. However, it is strange that routes are created (seemigly) properly but errors does not figure in them, so they are not properly set in sessions or where ever they are suposed to be set.

Comment: @lagbox how do I go about applying a middleware to a route in Laravel? Can you maybe make an answer here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the latest version of Laravel 5.2 you would have a `web` group of middleware that can be assigned to your routes. This particular middleware group is important as it provides your session support, `StartSession` middleware, which is what the authentication system uses by default and it provides a middleware for sharing the session errors with your views, `ShareErrorsFromSession` middleware (this is responsible for there being an `$errors` variable available to your views).

In a fresh install the `web` middleware group would already be applied to all your routes in your `routes.php` file. If it is not, which seems to be the case, you can make this adjustment in your `RouteServiceProvider`:

```
public function map(Router $router)
{
    $this->mapWebRoutes($router);

    //
}

protected function mapWebRoutes(Router $router)
{
    $router->group([
        'namespace' => $this->namespace,
        'middleware' => 'web', // <---- assigning the 'web' group middleware
    ], function ($router) {
        require app_path('Http/routes.php');
    });
}
```

If you prefer you can do this in your `routes.php` file instead:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'web'], function () {
    // your routes here
});
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your help! However, using the second way didn't work. For the first solution (adding code in RouteServiceProvider), there are several definitions of that class in the filesystem (strangely enough). Where should I add it? I see it in app/providers/RouteServiceProvider, but also in compiled.php and in vendor/laravel/framework/iluminate......

Comment: Worked! I added it in app/providers/RouteServiceprovider